# How to correctly align inline navpills with badge in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, word-wrap, badge, nav-pills

I have a menu made with stacked navpills on a left pane, where each page when clicked activates some other menu on the right; each pill contains a badge showing some additional context info for itself and what gets opened.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="pill">Introduction <span class=
  "badge pull-right">0/2</span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="pill">The effect of fear of humans on ease of handling of pigs <span class="badge pull-right">0/4</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="pill">Questionnaire <span class=
  "badge pull-right">0/4</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a problem in the wrapping of the pill contents, which I am not able to fix: when the width of the container is resized, the text and badge are wrapped accordingly, but there is a particular width for which only the badge gets wrapped, not the text, and the pill does not increase in height.

I am referring at the third section, second pill, of the following image ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uuvfpLk/) here):

[image]

What markup/css should I use to keep the badge aligned on the right, while having the text wrapping correctly leaving the space for it?

Comment: in your fiddle it looks fine to me, the badge doesn't move down like that.

Comment: Funny title.  Reads like "Mambo dogface to the banana patch" to me.

Comment: @floor that may depend on font width, you'll have to play with the width of the container div to see the effect

Comment: @Bob77 yeah you're right... completely open to suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `<span class="badge pull-right">0/4</span>` before the text which is inside the `<a></a>`.

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m24ho905/2/

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class=""><a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="pill"><span class=
  "badge pull-right">0/2</span> Introduction </a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab_4" data-toggle="pill"><span class="badge pull-right">0/4</span> The effect of fear of humans on
  ease of handling of pigs </a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="pill"><span class=
  "badge pull-right">0/4</span> Questionnaire </a></li>
</ul>
```